# Convert decimal to time HH:MM in MVC index

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a model with Hours, Hours_Registry and Remaining that cames from the BD:«, this is my model and my view

```
public Nullable<decimal> Hours { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Hours_Registry { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Remaining { get; set; }

<td data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hours_Registry)">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours_Registry)
                </td>
                <td data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Remaining)">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remaining)
                </td>
```

and know i want to convert the decimal in hours and minutes to diplay in index. how can i do it?
thanks

Comment: Can you be little more specific? Like what is Hours, Hours_Registry and Remaining holds? Like are those two digits? Also when you say "Convert" you mean to display?

Comment: @Rahatur it holds decimal values, like "10.20", yes display in index.

Comment: @PedroNuno the proper type to store durations in .NET is TimeSpan. `10.2` hours is 10 hours and 12 minutes. You can get a TimeSpan value from a decimal with `TimeSpan.FromHours()`, eg `TimeSpan.FromHours(10.2)`. You can make the conversion in the view but a better idea would be to change the properties to `TimeSpan` and use display attributes to control their display